# Inventory implementation in Java RPG

Tags: java, rpg

In my game (simple RPG with Java) there will be an abstract class Creature.

Critter, Beast, Vampire... will inherit from Creature. But not ALL classes that inherit from Creature will have an inventory.

Should I

a) make another abstract class such as CreatureWithInventory and inherit from it?

or

b) make an interface such as Inventory and make stuff as (Vampire implements Inventory)?

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other? Any considerable trade-offs?

Should Inventory itself be a class and let some Creatures have a field for it? If so, how would I test if Creature foo has Inventory? Is that even possible?

Comment: might i ask **why** critters do have an inventory? is it to keep the 'loot' inside or is the critter itself a looter and picks up items? or do items within the inventory modify stats of the critter?

Comment: answer this question can help to decide what kind of implementation is required ...

Comment: The inventory will be used as a loot container. A rabbit will have rabbit fur (or something similar) in its inventory.

Comment: I was asking because i was expecting this answer... don't judge me but consider the pros of my advice: use a dropping rule rather than implementingan inventory... you can apply this rule for several monsters... a rule needs no space to store (on disk AND in memory)... you alsoo don't have weird stuff in your inventory like fur or meat — remember that spell pickpocket in Ultima6 where you could steal those things from inventory)... if you have questions on looting rules, let me know...

Comment: "Letting you know." I could just google it, but you told me to let you know. I am clueless about how I would implement it.

Comment: hmm - i've added another answer but i'm not sure if this is the right place to put there..

Comment: maybe you open a new question.. i'll post my answer there again and give others the chance to contribute - maybe they have far better ideas than i do have ^^ (see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Inventory class with a matching field on the abstract class Creature seems best.

You can perform a null check against this field to see if a creature has an inventory.

This also allows you to reuse the inventory class as a field of non-creatures like bags, chests, rooms or anything else that suits your game.

Answer (score 3):

In general you should prefer *composition* over *inheritance* if answer to question "A is a B?" is "No". E.g. `Inventory` is a `Creature`? No, then it should be a component. But `Vampire` is a `Creature`, so it's logically inherited.

My [other answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66318/superclassing-rpg-game-entities/66319#66319) to similar question can also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointer out, you should generally prefer composition over inheritance(is-a vs. has-a):

```
public class Creature {
    private Inventory mInventory;

    public boolean hasInventory() {
        return mInventory != null;
    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return mInventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(Inventory inventory) {
        mInventory = inventory;
    }
}
```

This makes a much more flexible architecture in cases where you might want to make an exception for some specific creature. Consider the famous mudcrab merchant in Morrowind for example.

This approach lends itself well to data-drivenness as well. For example, if you would load all your creatures from JSON-files, you could specify a default creature with no inventory and specialize from that if needed:

vampire.json

```
{
  "type": "vampire",
  ...
}
```

frank.json

```
{
  "type": "vampire",
  "name": "Frank",
  "inventory": [
    { "item": "sword", "count": 1 },
    { "item": "gold", "count": 75 },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then while reading the creature definitions you could just check if a creature has the `inventory`-field and set it accordingly:

```
public Creature parseCreature(JsonObject json) {
    Creature creature;
    if (json.getString("type").equals("vampire")) {
        creature = new Vampire();
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    }

    if (json.has("inventory")) {
        creature.setInventory(parseInventory(json.getJsonObject("inventory")));
    }

    return creature;
}
```

As you can see, you can achieve many things that would be quite difficult with inheritance/interfaces.

Comment: "Consider the famous mudcrab merchant in Morrowind for example."
Awesome. A lot of stuff made more sense after reading this.

EDIT REASON: Enter without hold SHIFT.

Answer (score 0):

Create a drop rule:

here are my assuptions:

- you have a round based game
- you have a method that handles input (best case: as a command)
- you have a list for monsters and a currentMap

when will a drop rule apply? at the beginning of the monsters turn:

```
//assuming you have a kind of listener that handles all inputs
public void parseInput(Command cmd){

    //1. do players turn
    player.applyEffects(); //like poison or so
    boolean isDead = player.isDead(); //check life points
    if(!isDead){
       executeCommand(cmd);
    }else{
        ...
    }

    //2. do monsters turn
    for (Monster monster: monsterList){
         monster.applyEffects();
         boolean isDead = monster.isDead(); //check life points again

         if(isDead){
             applyDropRule(monster, currentMap); 

             //most important: remove the monster from the map!
             monster.markAsRemoved = true; //but you can't remove the monster right
                                           //now, because you're still iterating 
                                           //throug this list (see below)
         }else{
             ...
         }
    }

    //remove dead ones here
    List<Monster> removeList = new ArrayList<Monster>();
    for (Monster monster: monsterList){
        if(monster.markAsRemoved){
            removeList.add(monster);
        }
    }
    monsterList.removeAll(removeList );

    //3. let the environment do something too
    Field f = currentmap.getField(player.getPos() );
    if(f.isTrap() ){
        ...
    }
}
```

ok, as mentioned above this is an assupmtion, no we're coming to the interesting part: the drop rule:

again, i have to make another assumptions

- you know the dropping rules from books or ebooks

ok, then lets see how to do it ^^

```
public void applyDropRule(monster, currentMap){
    Field field = currentMap.getField(monster.getPos() );

    //dropList depending on current monster
    List<Item> dropList = DropCalculator.getDropsForMonster(monster.getType() );

    //another droplist depending on your level - maybe you can combine these two methods
    List<Item> goodyList = DropCalculator.getDropsForMap(currentMap.getType() );

    //adding 'default' items        
    for (Item item: dropList){
        field.addItem(item);
    }

    //adding goodies
    for (Item item: dropList){
        field.addItem(item);
    }

    //maybe adding a bloodstain (or a green squishy stain)
    if(monster.leavesStain){
         field.addDeco(...);
    }        
}
```

so ok, lets have a closer look at the dropCaluculator:

```
public class DropCalculator {

    //we have static access methods, you don't need an instance of this calculator
    //same as java.lang.Math
    public static List<Item> getDropsForMonster(MonsterType type){
        ArrayList<Item> dropList = new ArrayList();

        //it's always about probability
        //e.g. Sheep.chanceToLeaveCrorpse = 0.9 - most likely
        //e.g. Newt.chanceToLeaveCrorpse = 0.2 - not very likely
        //take these values from your rule book
        if (type.chanceToLeaveCorpse > Math.random() ){
            double nutritionValue = type.getNutrition;
            Item meat = ItemFactory.createItem(ItemType.Meat);
            meat.nutrition = nutritionValue;
            dropList.add(meat);
        }
    }

    return dropList;

}
```

there are a lot of rules that can be applied when a monster dies, so this is just a small impression of what can be done...

Comment: have you seen how OO-Programming can help you? if player and monster inherit from one class you can use `currentmap.getField(player.getPos() );` and `monster.isDead();` for both instances